# What does the AAAA in an AAAA record mean?

Tags: ip, ipv6, rfc

What does the AAAA in an AAAA record mean? I am guessing it is for address:address:address:address but couldn't even find a mention of AAAA in the [IPv6 specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2460.txt). Please provide a source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "In the standard DNS zone format you use AAAA records – or “quad-a”. A
>   32 bit IPv4 address is an A record. IPv6 is four times the size – 128
>   bits – so it ended up being a quad-A record."

Taken from: http://ipv6friday.org/blog/2012/01/ipv6-and-dn